# How do we draw the resultant of two unequal vectors at $0$ degrees and $180$ degrees?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-bundles

How do we draw the resultant of two unequal vectors at $0$ degrees and $180$ degrees?
I already know that,
Resultant of two vectors at $0$ degrees is the sum of the vectors and the direction of the resultant is same as the direction of given vectors.

Resultant of two vectors at $180$ degrees is the difference of the vectors and direction will be the direction of vector with greater magnitude.

I want to draw the resultant vector (which portion is the resultant). So, If you provide a photo with explanation that will be really helpful for me. And I also want to know whether is it possible to draw a resultant with the help of triangular or rectangular law. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show the parallelogram as it is flat.  The best I can do is below, showing a vector $5$ long opposed to one $2$ long.
[image]